# VS Code search and replace and change line order Vuejs

Tags: regex, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have this tag occurring in multiple files - same path but with different image files:

```
<img 
        id="logo"            
        style="margin-left:170px;margin-top:8px;width:85px"
        class="shrunk"
        src="~/static/img/poweredby-grey.png"
        alt=" logo" 
      >
```

I want to replace the src line everywhere BUT I also need to move the new :src line up in order because the Vue js linter will say the :src needs to be before class and style.

```
<img 
        id="logo"
        :src="require('~/static/' + imgURL + '/poweredby-grey.png')"            
        style="margin-left:170px;margin-top:8px;width:85px"
        class="shrunk"             
        alt=" logo" 
      >
```

I used regex replace and was able to replace the src line to the correct :src line. Given I have about 100 files to do this how can i do this quickly in VS Code?

My current search and replace regex is:

```
 src="~/static/img/(.+?)"
 :src="require('~/static/' + imgURL + '/$1')"
```

How can I adapt the two regex to search and replace across the whole `<img>` tag - this way in my replace regex I correct the line order at the same time.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use this as search string -   `(<img[\s\r?\n]+id.*?)([\r?\n\s]+style.+)([\r?\n\s]+class.+)+([\r?\n\s]+src.+)([\r?\n\s]+alt.+)[\r?\n\s]+>` Can you try this out ? I believe the order of these attributes are same as you mentioned in the example.....Use this as replacement string `$1$4$3$2$5>` - I tested it and it seems to work. Let me know how it goes for you. If this runs good then it changes the order of lines and next step you can run the regex to replace src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that [Multiline search](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_multiline-search) can help you here. You can create group for different properties and then rearrange it. Also [Search Editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_search-editors) feature of VS Code in combination with this [experimental plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakearl.search-editor-apply-changes) might help.

However I'd not recommend to use regexp for such transformation, if there is alternative.
The best possible way is to use autofix option of the rule (if it has it). I suspect that it is this rule that gives you an error: [attributes-order](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/attributes-order.html). In this case you can simply run `eslint` with `--fix` flag, and it'll reorder props automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it that keep your regex's a little simpler is to run two find and replaces in series.  Using an extension like [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) you can do this.

In your settings.json:

```
  "replacerules.rules": {

    "editImgSrc": {
      "find": "src=\"~/static/img/(.*?)\"",
      "replace": ":src=\"require('~/static/' + imgURL + '/$1')\""
    },
     "reorder vueImgSrc": {
                                              // get the src line and the two preceding lines
      "find": "((.*\r?\n){2})( *:src=\"require.*\r?\n)", 
      "replace": "$3$1"                                       // reorder them
    },
  },

  "replacerules.rulesets": {                // bundle the 2 find/replaces into one ruleset
  
    "Replace with vueImgSrc and reorder": {
      "rules": [
        "editImgSrc",
        "reorder vueImgSrc"
      ]
    }
  },
```

and then a keybinding to run that (in keybindings.json):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+w",                         // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "replacerules.runRuleset",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
    "args": {
        "rulesetName": "Replace with vueImgSrc and reorder"
    }
  },
```

---

[image: vue img src reorder demo]